# Indexing Multidimensional Arrays

Tags: indexing, julia

When indexing a multidimensional array in Julia.

```
arr = zeros(Int64, 5,5,5 )
ind = [1,1,1]
```

is there a better way to retrieve a value than the following

```
x = arr[ind...]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question, like how you define "better", but why not

```
x = arr[1,1,1]
```

?

Comment: Im trying to write a neural net with a user defined set of dimensions. Indexing a nodes metadata will be different for each dimension. Julia is complicated coming from python with lots of ins and outs that are non obvious and difficult sift out of the documentation, so Im looking for the way to index with an unknown # of dimensions in the way the builders of Julia intended.

Comment: Probably better to use a tuple, i.e. `(1,1,1)` than an array though. Much better chance that the compiler will be able to eliminate the overhead of splatting.